# How to pass current data from Adapter to Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

**Heterogeneous RecyclerView**

Hello friends I have a simple doubt

Here i am adding singleLineText

```
`addSingleLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String singleLineText = singleline.getText().toString();
            if(singleLineText.length() != 0)
            {
                mAdapter.addItem(singleLineText,null);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e(TAG,"adding single line text");
            }
            singleline.getText().clear();
        }
    });`
```

On this part i am adding MultiLineText

```
` addMultiLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String multiLineText = multiline.getText().toString();
            String myList[] = multiLineText.split(",");
            for(String item : myList)
            {
                mAdapter.addItem(null,item);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e(TAG,"adding multi line text");
            }
            multiline.getText().clear();
        }
    });
}`
```

My Adapter part of code:

```
` public void addItem(String singleLineText, String item) {
    Model model = new Model();
    if(item == null) {
        model.setText1(singleLineText);
        model.settingSingleLineText(true); // How to identify single line
    }
    else
    {
        model.setText2(item);
        model.settingMultiLineText(true); // How to identify multiple line
    }
    modelList.add(model);
}`
```

GetViewType Method:

```
` public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (modelList.get(position).IfSingleLine() != null)
        return VERTICAL;
    else {
        return HORIZONTAL;
    }
}`
```

Model class code snippet:

```
private Boolean checkSingleLine = null;

public Boolean IfSingleLine()
{
    return checkSingleLine;
}
public void settingSingleLineText(Boolean txt1)
{
    checkSingleLine = txt1;
}
public void settingMultiLineText(Boolean txt2)
{
    checkMultiLine = txt2;
}
```

`
**Problem:** How to identify the singleLineText and multiLineText by using the Model Class??

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. You want to pass "singleLineText " to your adapter ?

Comment: Yes Exactly so that i can display my text in View properly @Sam

Comment: your `verticallist` already has that. what else you need ?

Comment: when i add new `Text` item they are added along with the old Text items and getting displayed in  `TextView`.please refer this link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dou1.png]

Comment: can you add sample input and and sample output that you want ? also include the relevant code, so its easier to understand what exactly do you want.

Comment: i had posted the relevant code on my question @Sam

Comment: can you add your model class as well.

Comment: added code snippet @Sam

Comment: you have the booleans in your model class to differentiate between `singleLineText` and `multiLineText`. what is the problem that you are having ?

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCvVT.png] the old `singleLineText` are added along with the new `singleLineText` in TextView.

Comment: How would you like your output to look like ?

Comment: when i add `singleLineText` it should be added  `vertically` and when i add `multiLineText` it must be added in `horizontally` in  RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your `if (modelList.get(position).IfSingleLine() != null)`. `IfSingleLine()` will never be `null`. You want to check if it is `true` or `false` and this is not how you check for that.

Change your `getItemViewType` to the following and you will get correct orientation result from this function.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (modelList.get(position).IfSingleLine())
        return VERTICAL;
    else {
        return HORIZONTAL;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thank u so much for ur response.Is there is any way in this site to follow you @Sam

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow allows followers. But if my answer helped with your problem click the tick button to accept my answer.

Comment: k if my question is somewhat useful u can up vote my question